# Custom Ivy resolver documentation

Tags: gradle, ivy

I am writing my own Ivy resolver to be called by Gradle, written in Groovy.

I can correctly retrieve artifacts when I am refreshing or going to the repository but when the artifact is already cached it is failing. Does anyone have a link to documentation that will tell me the calls made at various points in the resolving process?

Comment: Be aware that using custom Ivy resolvers will no longer be supported in 2.x.

Comment: Fine, but I dont think that will be an issue for the project I am working on.

Do you have a link to some documentation?

Comment: I'm not aware of such documentation. Why do you use a custom resolver?

Comment: Within the organisation I am working at we have a bundle of libraries, we then specify a version of default for the library dependencies. I need the resolver to map the default to the version to the actual version. The custom resolver correctly maps the versions when downloading the dependencies but not when using a pre-cached dependency. I need the documentation to understand what is happening when resolving the cached dependencies.

Comment: I recommend to solve this differently, without a custom Ivy resolver. Instead you could hook into `someConfiguration.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {}`. For more information, see the Gradle user guide/DSL reference/sample builds.

Comment: Hmm, that looks interesting. That may just do it for me much easier. Thanks

Comment: This is sort of working for me.

I can get it to work if I put something in configurations in my build.gradle file, but what I really want to do is make this aplugin. How can I do this in an apply method or a plugin class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer relevant. As a result of the comments I am doing things a different way and have posted a new question relating to that ([Accessing configurations ResolutionStrategy from a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008006/accessing-configurations-resolutionstrategy-from-a-plugin))