# Accessing configurations ResolutionStrategy from a plugin

Tags: gradle

In my gradle dependencies I want to be able to use a version of 'default' and have that automatically map to a specific version of a library.

As an example I may have the following in my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile (group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-core', version 'default')
}
```

on resolution I want this to give me the equivalent of

```
dependencies {
    compile (group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-core', version '4.3.0.Beta4')
}
```

The mapping is specified in a file that contains key/value pairs of something like

```
org.hibernate.hibernate-core=4.3.0.Beta4
```

which is read into an extended property of type HashMap on the project called versionMap.

I can get this mapping to work quite happily with the following in my build.gradle file

```
configurations {
    all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.getVersion() == "default") {
                    def key = details.requested.getGroup() + "." + details.requested.getName() + ".version.default"
                    details.useVersion(versionMap.get(key))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I need to acknowledge the help of Peter Niederwieser for getting me this far)

As i need the same thing in a number of my projects I want to make this a plugin, so I have created a plugin project and it all build nicely but when I try and run it I cannot access the resolutionStrategy to set the logic. My plugin code looks like this:

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.DependencyResolveDetails;
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.ConfigurationContainer;
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy;

class DefaultVersionsPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    public void apply(Project project) {

        def strategy = 
            { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.getVersion() == "default") {
                    def key = details.requested.getGroup() + "." + details.requested.getName()
                    details.useVersion(ext.versionMap.get(key))
                }
            }

        ConfigurationContainer configurations = project.getConfigurations();
        configurations.each { config ->
            println "config: " + config + " - " + config.resolutionStrategy
            config.resoultionStrategy.eachDependency{ strategy }
        }
    }
}
```

The println above gives valid output but the line following gives an error. The output from running this plugin is.

```
config: configuration ':alerting:archives' - org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolutionstrategy.DefaultResolutionStrategy_Decorated@e2d0ab

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\trunk\build.gradle' line: 52

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'txlibs'.
> Could not find property 'resoultionStrategy' on configuration ':alerting:archives'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.975 secs
```

Is there any way to set the resolution strategy programatically? I have tried all manner of combinations to setting this but they all give the same error.

Comment: it's just a typo. it should be resolutionStrategy instead of resoultionStrategy

Comment: Any change your plugin is open sourced? I'm looking for something similar

Comment: Unfortunately not, this work was proprietary for a client I no longer have a ralationship with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now fixed this problem by changing the

```
ConfigurationContainer configurations = project.getConfigurations();
configurations.each { config ->
    println "config: " + config + " - " + config.resolutionStrategy
    config.resoultionStrategy.eachDependency{ strategy }
}
```

to

```
project.getConfigurations().all { config ->
    config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency{ DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (details.requested.getVersion() == "default") {
            def key = details.requested.getGroup() + "." + details.requested.getName() + ".version.default"
            details.useVersion(project.ext.versionMap.get(key))
         }
    }
}
```

and moving the closure definition inline (not sure if the inline made any impact or not).

Comment: It's `all` vs. `each`. `all` will also catch configurations that will be added later on, after the plugin has run.

Comment: Great, thanks for this. Its certainly good to know why something is happening so  I don't make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just the typo in

```
config.resoultionStrategy
```

or is just an example rather than the real thing?

Comment: Not quite, but thanks for spotting that. 

The error above has now disappeared but it does not seem to set the resolution strategy because the dependency download is failing.

Comment: A couple of things: can you be sure that the resolution strategy gets called; and can you see that it retrieves the right thing using ext.versionMap?

Comment: I just tried it and that 'ext.versionMap' syntax doesn't work for me in a plugin like that. However, 'project.versionMap' works fine.

Comment: I have now got this working, thanks in no small part to you spotting my stupid typo. I have been staring at that all day. I will post the final fix in a separate answer to this question.