# Setting resolution strategy for detached configurations

Tags: gradle

Further to this question, [Accessing configurations ResolutionStrategy from a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008006/accessing-configurations-resolutionstrategy-from-a-plugin)

I am now happily setting the resolution strategy for my projects and the build works fine. The resolution strategy will accept a version of default and map that to an actual version of the librarys, resolving it correctly.

However, I am unable to generate idea or eclipse projects because the detached configurations are unable to resolve the default version.

Is there a way to set the resolution strategy for detached configurations?

*** EDIT ***

The error I get when I run the build with the plugin applied is:

```
:ideaProject FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ideaProject'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration4'.
   > Module version group:xxx, module:mmm, version:trunk, configuration:detachedConfiguration4 declares a dependency on configuration 'default' which is not declared in the module descriptor for group:xxx, module:nnn, version:trunk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

I have assumed that because I am setting the resolutionStrategy with configurations.all and this is a detached configuration then the resolutionStrategy is not being applied to the detached configuration.

Comment: Please elaborate on "I am unable to generate idea or eclipse projects". What exactly is the problem? What exact error message do you get? Etc.

Comment: Because the configurations the plugin creates to resolve dependencies are detached they do not use the resolutionStrategy I apply to all configurations detailed in my previous question. Therefore the plugin fails to resolve a dependency because it cannot find a version of default, in a normal build this default version will be mapped within the resolutionStrategy

Comment: Which artifact cannot be resolved? The main artifact or the Javadoc/sources?

Comment: Can you show your evidence? As far as I remember, the IDEA plugin (and likely also Eclipse) only uses detached configurations for Javadoc and sources, and that's also what I see in the code. And to answer your question, you can set the resolution strategy for a detached configuration if you have a reference to it.

Comment: Added the error to the question

Comment: Looking at this in a little more detail I do not actually understand why it does what it does. module nnn can be resolved locally or through ivy. The project is set up to resolve locally with project compile(':nnn') in the dependencies but the plugin is finding the module from the ivy repo.

Comment: It's not resolving the main artifact, but the Javadoc or sources artifact. Until Javadoc and sources become part of Gradle's dependency model (and not just the IDE model), you may have to disable downloading of Javadoc and sources, and if necessary, implement resolution of Javadoc and sources yourself.

Comment: That solves the problem but I get a deprecation warning when I set the downloadJavadoc to false.

Comment: Ignore the above. I would remove the comment but I can't. I had a type in the downloadJavadoc which was giving me the warning.